# how to create a linked server using ODBC correctly?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server

can someone please let me know the steps on creating a linked server using ODBC connection? thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this page:

- http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

which has a walk through on creating a linked server to MySQL using an ODBC driver.

Comment: @jayt.dev hopefully the original link comes back up, but you can see also view the [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20160913151958/http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/)